# Spring JavaMailSenderImpl javax.mail.NoSuchProviderException: smtp

Tags: spring, smtp, jakarta-mail

I have a very large project with a ton of dependancies, and am getting the following exception when trying to send mail:

```
javax.mail.NoSuchProviderException: smtp
```

I know the code works because it is part of a library that is used in other projects.  Does anyone know what would cause this exception to happen? I have looked through all of the jar's and the only one containing 'javax.mail' is 'mail-1.4.4-SNAPSHOT.jar'.

Is there some file/class that registeres the 'smtp' protocol, and it could be happening somewhere else in my classpath?

Answer (score 7):

It's been a while since this question has been asked but it's still worth answering :

What's happening is that your mail service is using the SMTP (usually, it is even considered as the default protocol to use)protocol to send mail. No matter what concrete class you're using as mail service (might depend on whether you're working with Java EE, Spring or something else), it ends up using classes from the javamail API. In this API, in order to establish a connection to your mail server, an instance of javax.mail.Session will be created and this object will dynamically load classes that provide support for the protocol to use.

When loading the required class, in case it is not found, the ClassNotFoundException is caught and re-threw as javax.mail.NoSuchProviderException, with a message indicating the missing protocol support.

The solution in that case is to add the smtp.jar to your classpath.
With a Maven-based project, simply add the following dependency

```
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.sun.mail</groupId>
        <artifactId>smtp</artifactId>
        <version>1.4.5</version>
    </dependency>
```

Answer (score 3):

I had this issue. Putting smtp.jar in classpath solved the issue.

Comment: Adding the SMTP.jar solved this problem for me just now.

Answer (score 2):

The way I have fixed this was to remove the mail jar from the classpath. Somewhere in the classpath there exists another instance of mail.jar, and I have yet been able to find it.  If anyone else runs into this problem, additional information on trouble shooting can be found here:

http://forum.springsource.org/showthread.php?t=90737
and
http://forums.sun.com/thread.jspa?threadID=5442371

Answer (score 2):

I got same problem while we upgrade jboss from 4.x to 6.x.

Here Problem is setting classpath to the more number of mail.jar files(default server will take the mail.jar from its common/lib foler if it available there).
To confirm which jar file it is using, following statement is usefull.

**System.out.println(getClass().getResource("/javax/mail/Address.class"));**

if it is using the another jar file which you are not expecting.. set classpath to that instead which you are using. other wise remove that jar file from the above printed location.

Answer (score 1):

This can also happen when you have an incorrect version of the "mailapi.jar" file in your classpath as well.

I'd recently upgraded a project to use PayPal's soap API, and PayPal's distribution contained a mailapi.jar file, which was different than the one I'd currently had in my project, and caused my app to fail when sending mail.

So for me, I just had to revert to my old mailapi.jar and I was fine.

Comment: This was the cause of the same problem for me. Thanks for the pointer, checked I had the library so many times before noticing it was now PayPals.

Answer (score 1):

I had this isssue right now. The problem was two javax.mail.jar in the same classpath.